# Remove decimals y axis ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this, `df_Filtered`:

```
Product Relative_Value
Car     0.12651458
Plane   0.08888552
Tank    0.03546231
Bike    0.06711630
Train   0.06382191
```

I want to make a bar plot of the data in GGplot2:

```
ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Product, y = Relative_Value, fill = Product)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    labs(x ="Product", y = "Percentage of total sell", title = "Japan 2010") +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

How do i get rid of the decimals on the y-axis in the chart? So that it says `20 %` instead of `20.0 %`?

Comment: One option is to manually create the breaks and labels. Use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.05), labels = paste0(seq(0,1,0.05)*100," %"))` instead.

Comment: That would be a solution, the problem is just that I want to make 40 bar plots with different scales on `Relative_Value`.

Comment: I thought it would always be a percentage value on your y axis. This would get everything from 0% to 100%.

Comment: That is true! I just don't know if I want it to be from 0-100, I might want it to be scaled dynamic. But I will keep this solution in mind if I want that scale. :)

Comment: It won't show all breaks if it's not needed though. If you run the small example you posted using that code you'll see. So, it is dynamic in that sense.

Comment: You are right! That's great, it solved my problem! Thanks a lot

Comment: You'd have the issue you described only if you were using (fixed) values within `ylim` function, as that would fix the y range.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `percent_format` from the `scales` package to set `accuracy` to 1.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(df_Filtered, aes(x = Product, y = Relative_Value, fill = Product)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
labs(x ="Product", y = "Percentage of total sell", title = "Japan 2010") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df_Filtered <- read.table(text = "Product Relative_Value
Car     0.12651458
                 Plane   0.08888552
                 Tank    0.03546231
                 Bike    0.06711630
                 Train   0.06382191",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Was just checking this! :) Interestingly `percent_format(1)` shows 5% on y axis instead of 4%.

Comment: @AntoniosK Interesting I thought `percent_format(1)` should be the same as `percent`, but they are not.

Comment: Thanks! That one works great except from the problem that I get 4 % instead of 5 %, as @AntoniosK points out.

Comment: From `format_percent`: "Accuracy: A number to round to. Use (e.g.) 0.01 to show 2 decimal places of precision.". Most the time you will want 1.

Comment: @www it is probably worth updating your answer to `accuracy = 1` if you agree, as it's not obvious at all (I assumed it would behave like `round()`, so my first attempt to get whole number percents was to use `accuracy = 0`, but that returned NA.

Comment: @stevec Thanks for looking into this and your suggestions. I have updated my post for `accuracy = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`scales::percent_format(accuracy = 2)` doesn't allow manual `breaks = c(0, 0.5, .10)`.
So, I have to create the manual function `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.5, .10), labels = function(x) paste0(round(as.numeric(x*100)), "%"))` .